# How to see xpath location of error when doing XSD or RelaxNG validation?

Tags: xpath, xsd, schematron, relaxng, svrl

We're generating HTML preview of an XML schema (EAD 2002) and want to embed validation errors as hovers/tooltips in the respective HTML location.

We've done it for some custom Schematron rules (which output SVRL that includes the xpath location of the error), but can't do it for the basic EAD schema.

Is there a XSD or RelaxNG validator that outputs the xpath location of errors?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a XSD or RelaxNG validator that outputs the xpath location of errors?

There is rng-extension (https://github.com/transpect/rng-extension), a Relax NG validation extension for XML Calabash (http://xmlcalabash.com/). Haven't used either myself, though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I analyzed it a bit and we'll try to adapt LtxValidateWithRNG.java to run outside of Calabash and produce SVRL reports. Ideally, we'll add it as a `-svrl` option to jing (that source uses a patched jing)

Comment: Also, for posterity, there is an open Jing ticket to add XPath paths to the error output: https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang/issues/158

Comment: Thanks, we'll be working on implementing this for standalone Jing (will report on github), and may integrate in http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Validation_Module#validate:rng-report

Comment: We implemented this at https://github.com/EHRI/jing-trang/pull/1